# Kafka Connect using REST API with Strimzi with kind: KafkaConnector

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I'm trying to use Kafka Connect REST API for managing connectors, for simplicity consider the following `pause` implementation:

```
def pause(): Unit = {
      logger.info(s"pause() Triggered")
      val response = HttpClient.newHttpClient.send({
        HttpRequest
          .newBuilder(URI.create(config.connectUrl + s"/connectors/${config.connectorName}/pause"))
          .PUT(BodyPublishers.noBody)
          .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(config.timeout.toMillis.toInt))
          .build()
      }, BodyHandlers.ofString)
      if (response.statusCode() != HTTPStatus.Accepted) {
        throw new Exception(s"Could not pause connector: ${response.body}")
      }
    }
```

Since I'm using `KafkaConnector` as a resource, I cannot use Kafka Connect REST API because the connector operator has the KafkaConnetor resources as its single source of truth, manual changes such as `pause` made directly using the Kafka Connect REST API are reverted by the Cluster Operator.

So to pause the connector I need to edit the resource in some way.

I'm struggling to change the logic of the current function, It will be great to have some practical examples of how to handle KafkaConnetor resources.

I check out the [Using Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/using.html) doc but couldn't find any practical example

Thanks!

---

After help from @Jakub i managed to create my new client:

```
class KubernetesService(config: Configuration) extends StrictLogging {

  private[this] val client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(Config.autoConfigure(config.connectorContext))

  def setPause(pause: Boolean): Unit = {
    logger.info(s"[KubernetesService] - setPause($pause) Triggered")

    val connector = getConnector()
    connector.getSpec.setPause(pause)
    Crds.kafkaConnectorOperation(client).inNamespace(config.connectorNamespace).withName(config.connectorName).replace(connector)

    Crds.kafkaConnectorOperation(client)
      .inNamespace(config.connectorNamespace)
      .withName(config.connectorName)
      .waitUntilCondition(connector => {
        connector != null &&
          connector.getSpec.getPause == pause && {
          val desiredState = if (pause) "Paused" else "Running"
          connector.getStatus.getConditions.stream().anyMatch(_.getType.equalsIgnoreCase(desiredState))
        }
      }, config.timeout.toMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  }

  def delete(): Unit = {
    logger.info(s"[KubernetesService] - delete() Triggered")

    Crds.kafkaConnectorOperation(client).inNamespace(config.connectorNamespace).withName(config.connectorName).delete

    Crds.kafkaConnectorOperation(client)
      .inNamespace(config.connectorNamespace)
      .withName(config.connectorName)
      .waitUntilCondition(_ == null, config.timeout.toMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  }

  def create(oldKafkaConnect: KafkaConnector): Unit = {
    logger.info(s"[KubernetesService] - create(${oldKafkaConnect.getMetadata}) Triggered")

    Crds.kafkaConnectorOperation(client).inNamespace(config.connectorNamespace).withName(config.connectorName).create(oldKafkaConnect)

    Crds.kafkaConnectorOperation(client)
      .inNamespace(config.connectorNamespace)
      .withName(config.connectorName)
      .waitUntilCondition(connector => {
          connector != null &&
          connector.getStatus.getConditions.stream().anyMatch(_.getType.equalsIgnoreCase("Running"))
      }, config.timeout.toMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  }

  def getConnector(): KafkaConnector = {
    logger.info(s"[KubernetesService] - getConnector() Triggered")
    Try {
      Crds.kafkaConnectorOperation(client).inNamespace(config.connectorNamespace).withName(config.connectorName).get
    } match {
      case Success(connector) => connector
      case Failure(_: NullPointerException) => throw new NullPointerException(s"Failure on getConnector(${config.connectorName}) on ns: ${config.connectorNamespace}, context: ${config.connectorContext}")
      case Failure(exception) => throw exception
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *pause* the connector, you can edit the `KafkaConnector` resource and set the `pause` field in `.spec` to `true` (see the [docs](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/using.html#type-KafkaConnectorSpec-reference)). There are several options how you can do it. You can use `kubectl` and either apply the new YAML from file (`kubectl apply`) or do it interactively using `kubectl edit`.

If you want to do it programatically, you will need to use a Kubernetes client to edit the resource. In Java, you can also use the `api` module of Strimzi which has all the structures for editing the resources. I put together a simple example for pausing the Kafka connector in Java using the Fabric8 Kubernetes client and the `api` module:

```java
package cz.scholz.strimzi.api.examples;

import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.MixedOperation;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.Resource;
import io.strimzi.api.kafka.Crds;
import io.strimzi.api.kafka.KafkaConnectorList;
import io.strimzi.api.kafka.model.KafkaConnector;

public class PauseConnector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String namespace = "myproject";
        String crName = "my-connector";

        KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
        MixedOperation<KafkaConnector, KafkaConnectorList, Resource<KafkaConnector>> op = Crds.kafkaConnectorOperation(client);
        KafkaConnector connector = op.inNamespace(namespace).withName(crName).get();
        connector.getSpec().setPause(true);
        op.inNamespace(namespace).withName(crName).replace(connector);

        client.close();
    }
}
```

*(See https://github.com/scholzj/strimzi-api-examples for the full project)*

I'm not a Scala users - but I assume it should be usable from Scala as well, but I leave rewriting it from Java to Scala to you.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jakub, Is there a good reference for `strimzi-api`? for example making operations such as `delete` and `recreate` with new `config`?

Comment: and also if it is possible to find all the current offsets for specific `groupId` since currently I'm using adminClient (`org.apache.kafka.clients.admin`) in order to find the offsets

Comment: _"also if it is possible to find all the current offsets for specific groupId since currently I'm using adminClient"_ ... Well, the Admin client is the right way for this. But I'm not sure how easy or hard that is.

Comment: _"Thank you very much @Jakub, Is there a good reference for strimzi-api? for example making operations such as delete and recreate with new config?"_ ... Well, for creating, you can just use the `create` command instead of `replace`. You can use the `KafkaConnectorBuilder` to prepare the resource. Similarly with `delete` or to update the configuration etc. You just manupulate the custom resources.

Comment: why should i replace the old connector with new one, doesn't just `op.inNamespace(namespace).withName(crName).get().getSpec().setPause(true)` should work? also If i give the K8sClient the namespace, do i need to specify it also on the `.inNamespace` method?

Comment: `op.inNamespace(namespace).withName(crName).get().getSpec().setPause(true)` This would just change the local object. Only something like `replace` or `patch` does the actual call to the Kubernetes API. This is how the Fabric8 Kubernetes lcient works: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client

Comment: I see that there authentication permissions: `Failure executing: GET at: https://rancher-prod.companyName.io/k8s/clusters/c-p6z2t/apis/kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2/namespaces/aerospike-connect/kafkaconnectors. Message: 404 page not found` with error: `{"type": "error","status": "401","message": "Unauthorized 401: must authenticate"
}` - any ideas? (result of `Crds.kafkaConnectorOperation(client).inNamespace("aerospike-connect")`)

Comment: rancher is the `masterUrl` btw

Comment: Right, so ... 401 means you do not have the right to do the operation - so you need someone to give you the RBAC rights (if you run it through your user acount) or setup the RBAC Role/RoleBinding/Service account if you run it in some Pod. the 404 usually means that the CRD does not exist. Assuming this is based on the example I provided, it might be that you are using an older Strimzi version which does not have the v1beta2 version yet. In which case you might need to use the older version of the Strimzi `api` module.

Comment: Thanks @Jakub, really helpful! - Regarding the 404, this is the warning I'm getting: `2021-07-27 15:45:58,928 [ScalaTest-run-running-KubernetesServiceSpec] WARN  i.f.k.c.internal.VersionUsageUtils - The client is using resource type 'kafkaconnectors' with unstable version 'v1beta2'`  and i'm using `"io.strimzi" % "api" % "0.24.0"` with `apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
`, `FROM strimzi/kafka:0.20.0-kafka-2.6.0` - if i downgrade to `0.20` the `api`  module it will warn me on `The client is using resource type 'kafkaconnectors' with unstable version 'v1alpha1'`

Comment: The `with unstable version` message is something you can just ignore.

Comment: Thanks @Jakub, i re-edit the post with the new client

Comment: last question: I want to re-create KafkaConnector so first of all I `.get()` the current Connector and then I .`delete()` and then I'm creating as follows: `Crds.kafkaConnectorOperation(k8s).inNamespace(connectorNamespace).withName(connectorName).create(connector)` which throw exception `Failure executing: POST at: https://rancher-prod.companyName.io/... Message: resourceVersion should not be set on objects to be created. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=500, details=null, kind=Status, message=resourceVersion should not be set on objects to be created.`, any ideas? - Thanks!

Comment: Why are you recreating it like this? Why not just update it? In any case I think the error suggestes you should not use the connector from the `get()` method - you should build a new instalce.

Comment: since i need to delete it, i'm reset the offset which will fail if the connector is paused/running, so how can I create new instance based on the `.get()`? I mean without losing any relevant data - is there a quick example to create the same connector?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow ... you delete the connector ... without loosing data ... maybe it would best to move this to some chat on the CNCF Slack or something where you can properly explain what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: Sure @Jakub, sent you a message :) thanks!